# UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView

Tags: android, list, android-activity, view, android-layoutparams

I am trying to create a simple Android app and I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twista.shopinglist/com.twista.shopinglist.ItemDetail}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

I tried to google it and fix via some answers here, but unsuccessfuly it didn't resolve :(.

I have a `MainActivity` with `ListView`, in `onCreate()` I call

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ....

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.overListView);

    List<Item> values = dataSource.getItems();

    final ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Item i = adapter.getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemDetail.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putLong("my_id", i.getId());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

this code should start new activity, `ItemDetail`, whose code is here:

```
public class ItemDetail extends Activity {

private ItemsDataSource dataSource;

private long itemId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    itemId = bundle.getLong("my_id");
    Intent intent = getIntent();


    dataSource = new ItemsDataSource(this);
    try {
        dataSource.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.detailListView);

    List<SubItem> values = dataSource.getSubItemOfItem(itemId);

    ArrayAdapter<SubItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<SubItem>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

i'm still get this error:

```
09-10 22:30:30.555  10695-10695/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.twista.shopinglist/com.twista.shopinglist.ItemDetail}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
    at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:477)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:750)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:323)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
    at com.twista.shopinglist.ItemDetail.onCreate(ItemDetail.java:27)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
```

layout file for second (detail activity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/detailListView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupSub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_sub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add New"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_sub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete First"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ListView>
```

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your XML file contains Views that are children of a ListView, you cannot do this. Your XML file should look liks this:

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:id="@+id/detailListView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupSub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_sub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add New"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_sub"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Delete First"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```